# GitHub Branch Protection - Requiring PRs versus Push Restriction

Tags: git, branch

I recently added branch restriction to the master branch of my repository.

The standard workflow for contributing is via PRs, so I enabled `Require pull request reviews before merging` and included the setting to dismiss stale reviews.

I would also like to push directly to the master myself but block that action for others with write access to the repository, so I enabled `Restrict who can push to matching branches` and added only myself.

Now, when I attempt to push to the master directly, the branch protection rejects my push with the message `At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.` It seems that GitHub is enforcing the first check, even though I should have permission to bypass this.

Is it possible to both require approval of PRs for merging while still allowing myself to push directly?

If not, what is the purpose of the push restriction setting when the PR setting is enabled?

Comment: Great question. I wish there was an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could have changed since first posted, but this sounds like `Include administrators` option is enabled.

That said I am also confused about what the `Require pull request reviews before merging` and `Restrict who can push to matching branches` means when they're used together, as the first should restrict push access as well.